# How to set filter for folder on Email server by C#

Tags: c#, email, imap

I'm writing an email client, and I need to implement creating folders and setting the filter for a folder.

I have a problem with the second task: how can I do this programmatically using C#?
I've tried several IMAP libraries (s22, ae.net.mail, mailkit etc.), but they can only create folders; there is no way to configure filters.

Maybe I've missed something. I will be glad for any advice.

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597(v=office.15).aspx) is how Outlook does it. By "my email-client" do you mean a client you wrote from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IMAP protocol doesn't specify a way to configure mail filters, so the way to do this will be highly dependent on the mail server.

Some servers support the [Sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_%28mail_filtering_language%29) filtering language and the associated ManageSieve protocol.